# Hessian-Matrix positive definite $\iff$ $a$ local minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

It is commonly known that if $f$ is twice differentiable, $\nabla f(a) = 0$ and  $H_f(a)$ positive definite, $a$ is a local minimum.

So, in short: $H_f(a)$ positive definite $ \implies $ $a$ local minimum

But what about " $\impliedby $ " ? What can I say about the Hessian-Matrix, when I know $a$ is a local minimum?

Do cases exist, where $a$ is a local minimum and the Hessian-Matrix is **not** positive definite ?

Comment: Try $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ at $x=y=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed such cases exist.  For example, consider the function $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$ given

$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_1^n x_i^{2m}, \tag{1}$

where $m \ge 2$.  We have

$\nabla f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = 2m(x_1^{2m - 1}, x_2^{2m -1}, \ldots, x_n^{2m -1}); \tag{2}$

the only critical point of $f$ occurs at $0$, and it is evidently a global minimum.  But the matrix of second derivatives of $f$ is

$H(f) = 2m(2m - 1)\text{diag}(x_1^{2m - 2}, x_2^{2m -2}, \ldots, x_n^{2m - 2}), \tag{3}$

that is, the diagonal matrix whose $ii$ entry is $2m(2m -1)x_i^{m - 2}$; clearly

$H(f)(0) = 0. \tag{4}$

Thus $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ provides an example of a function with a unique global minimum at $0$, but a vanishing Hessian there.  This is a case such as the OP sought in his question; evidently, there are many more such examples; constructing such is not too hard.

I think the best you can say is that $H(f)(a)$ must be positive semi-definite; it cannot have any negative eigenvalues, lest $f$ take on a value less that $f(a)$ in neighborhoods of $a$; it may, however, have eigenvalues equal to $0$, as the above example illustrates.

Comment: why can it not have negative eigenvalues? I get the idea that it is forbidden that a neighborhood exists in which f(a) > f(a+v), but how do I show this formally?

Comment: @Christian:  I'm editing in a few notes on this; gimme a few minutes, if you please!  Thanks!

Comment: @Christian:  sorry this taking so long!  Had to go to work.  Will try and address your questions soon!  Cheers!

Comment: No hurry, you are the one helping me...